# convert integer to a character

Tags: java, character, integral

I am having a problem with my java code, basically I want to do this;

```
char letter = 'a';
char convertedletter = letter + 5;
System.out.print(convertedletter);
```

the output should be `f`, but the output I get is `108`. How could I make it an `f`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
char letter = 'a';
char convertedletter;
convertedletter = (char) (letter + 5);
System.out.print(convertedletter);
```

The operator "+" is used to add numbers or concatenate String, since you are using it whit a char (only one character) and a int it would return a int unless you converted it to char with is what you want.

Comment: thanks for the answer!! Really appreciated it, really needed the answer cause I'm already nearing a deadline for my project.Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

You should have [cast](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) while adding. As `5` is integer, `convertedletter` get converted to Integer and hence you get output as 108 as ascii value of 'a' is 103.

Use should have

```
char convertedletter = (char) (letter + 5);
```

Also read [this](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/TypeCasting.shtml), [this](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1170) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
char convertedletter = (char) (letter + 5);
```